# How to fix background-image position after increasing scale of page?

Tags: html, css

I have `div` block with the following styles:

```
.promo-blocks .first-appointment {
    background-image: url("../images/41d000_e4b9806a75b61053f1d6d4ccab8903df.png_srz_980_345_85_22_0.50_1.20_0 (2).00_png_srz");

    position: relative;
    background-color: #82B440;
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: -97%;
    background-size: contain;

}
```

When I increase the scale of the page to 75% or less then my `background-image` is shifted to the left side.
How I can fix this background at the position `left bottom` and with constant padding from center text?

Comment: Only Javascript I think.. Why not make an <img> and use percentage for width and height?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Have you tried background-size: cover? It centers your background and fits it in the whole div.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with jQuery on resize event

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   var size = ...
   $(".promo-blocks .first-appointment").css("background-position-x",size);
});
```

and calculate `size` pram based on some logic which you need

For example

1) keep window old size and take new size in window resize event and according to diff of that values set background-position-x

2) you can use % differences of screen width etc ..

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this line:

```
background-position-x: -97%;
```

try without.

maybe also

```
background-position: left;
```